# Change ul's style onclick - css/jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have this simple menu with some `<ul>`s that loads its content onclicking on it.
And I want to change the style of every ul on loading the content that belongs to it.
Here's the menu: http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant styling the corresponding parent `li` (with the border bottom using the class `current`) as you are doing for the first one by default. You can try this:

```
$('.current').not(
             $(this)
               .closest('li')
               .addClass('current'))
.removeClass('current');
```

or just

```
$(this)
       .closest('li') //Get to the parent li
       .addClass('current') //add the class current
       .siblings('.current') // select the sibling with the same class  (previous selection)
       .removeClass('current'); //remove the class from there
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cgXs9/)

- [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
- [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)
- [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Comment: @user2401856 You are welcome. Probably you should rephrase your questions. That is a bit confusing.. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
$(this).closest('ul').addClass('newStyle');
```

Though within a click-handler (assuming nested `ul` elements):

```
$('li').click(function(e){
    $(e.target).closest('ul').addClass('newStyle');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ttfEL/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).